# CellClick event: Selection from combo-box not smooth

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with two columns. One is `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` and other is `DataGridViewButtonColumn`. To capture the button click from the `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, i have written the `CellClick` event and it is working fine. However, this is not making my selection from the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` 'smooth'. What i mean is that i have to click on the combo-box twice for it to show the drop-down list. I have noticed that at every click, `CellClick` is fired. But only after the second click the drop-down pops out. What is the work-around for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by setting `DataGridView`'s `EditMode` property to `EditOnEnter` as stated here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/c461b774-ece5-4fdd-86c5-90e5b6426690/

Answer (score 0):

The best work around I found is to keep the current row selected as the mouse move over it to prevent clicking more than once, one to bring focus to current row and second to choose the combo box drop down list, Add the Following Code to the mouse move event of datagrid:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseMove
    Dim theRow As Integer = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
    If theRow < 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(theRow).Cells(0)
End Sub
```

Comment: it is still not working. I still have to click twice on the combo-box for it to show the drop-down.